# Mongoose Cast to ObjectId failed for value "X_Value" (type string) at path "_id" for model "X_Model"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am trying to update multiple records at once via id.
I am getting the error below. I have ensured /weather/:id is below /weather/updateMultiple. I can't work out the issue (neither can ChatGPT). Help please.

> **Cast to ObjectId failed for value "updateMultiple" (type string) at path "_id" for model "Weather"**

**Code:**

```
//update multiple data in 'weather' collection (PUT http://localhost:3000/weather/updateMultiple)
app.put('/weather/updateMultiple', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const updates = req.body;

        // Array to store updated documents
        const updatedWeatherArray = [];

        // Iterate over each update object in the request body
        for (const update of updates) {
            const { _id, ...fieldsToUpdate } = update; 

            // Find and update the document
            const updatedWeather = await Weather.findByIdAndUpdate(_id, fieldsToUpdate, { new: true });

            // Cannot find record in DB
            if (!updatedWeather) {
                return res.status(404).json({ message: `Cannot find field with ID ${_id}` });
            }

            // Add the updated document to the array
            updatedWeatherArray.push(updatedWeather);
        }

        // Found records and updated
        res.status(200).json(updatedWeatherArray);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
});



//update data in 'weather' collection (PUT http://localhost:3000/weather/:id)
app.put('/weather/:id', async (req, res) => {....
```

**SCHEMA:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const weatherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    _id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true
    },
    "Device Name": {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    "Precipitation mm/h": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    Time: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    },
    Latitude: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    Longitude: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Temperature (°C)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Atmospheric Pressure (kPa)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Max Wind Speed (m/s)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Solar Radiation (W/m2)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Vapor Pressure (kPa)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Humidity (%)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    "Wind Direction (°)": {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
});

const Weather = mongoose.model('Weather', weatherSchema, 'weather'); // 'weather' is the collection name

module.exports = Weather;
```

**Input**

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/weather/updateMultiple

[
    {
        "_id": "65714e17a36f8c7d905f599f",
        "Device Name": "Updated_Device_UPDATE_MULTIPLE_1",
        "Humidity (%)": 75.0
    },
    {
        "_id": "65714e17a36f8c7d905f59a0",
        "Device Name": "Updated_Device_UPDATE_MULTIPLE_2",
        "Humidity (%)": 80.0
    }
]
```

Comment: Your `/weather/:id` route is picking up this request and trying to convert the word `updateMultiple` to an `ObjectId` in a `Model.findById()` method. Please post your routes so that someone can help you debug.

Comment: Are routes case sensitive?  I notice the error message has `"Weather"` but the routes are `/weather/`

Answer (score -1):

Just a silly mistake. I didn't realise nodemon wasn't running and I had to manually restart the server to update everything. So the code here was actually working, just not live essentially.